# chamadas php por ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho um ficheiro em PHP que me devolve um Json.

Esse ficheiro PHP é chamado por Ajax, não tenho funções no ficheiro do PHP. Recebo as variáveis por POST no ficheiro do PHP...

Esta tudo a funcionar, mas agora quero adicionar no PHP funções e receber por parâmetro os dados , neste momento estou a fazer assim:

```
var pesquisa = $("#pesquisa").serialize();$.ajax({ 
 type: "POST",
    url: "../Logica/info/Getinfo.php",
    dataType: 'json',     
    data: pesquisa,
```

Claro é que no ficheiro PHP não tenho classes nem funções, 
no PHP recebo os parâmetros por `$var=  $_POST["key"];`

Agora quero meter o ficheiro com funções e que fiquem a funcionar... Como consigo fazer isso?

```
function getinfo($key,$query,$datainicio,$datafim,$op){

    if ($op != "" and ( $datainicio != "" and $datafim != "")) {
        $query = "$querys $op and (datainicio >:datainicio AND datafim<:datafim)";
        $db = new ligacao();
        $conn = $db->open();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':datainicio', $datainicio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':datafim', $datafim, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
        if ($key != "") {
        $query = "$querys  KEY=:KEY";
        $db = new ligacao();
        $conn = $db->open();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':KEY', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $table = array();
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    $table['data'] = $rows;
    $json = json_encode($table);
    echo ($json);

}
```

Comment: Se bem entendi, você quer utilizar funções com os parâmetros vindos via POST, basta você pegar as variaveis atribuidas como você mesmo exemplificou($var=  $_POST["key"]) e passa-las para as funções. Posta ai alguma coisa que você já fez neste arquivo php para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: vou editar o codigo

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa pegar os dados via POST, e depois chamar sua função com os valores capturados:

```
$key = $_POST["key"];

$datainicio = $_POST["datainicio"];

$datafim = $_POST["datafim"];

$op = $_POST[]"op"];
```

Depois, basta iniciar um objeto da sua classe e chamar o método, passando estes valores. O arquivo pode ficar assim, mas por questão de organização, é aconselhável que você separe a classe num arquivo próprio.

```
$key = $_POST["key"];

$datainicio = $_POST["datainicio"];

$datafim = $_POST["datafim"];

$op = $_POST[]"op"];

$suaClasse = new SuaClasse();

$suaClasse->getinfo($key, $query, $datainicio, $datafim, $op);


class SuaClasse{

    function getinfo($key,$query,$datainicio,$datafim,$op){

        if ($op != "" and ( $datainicio != "" and $datafim != "")) {
            $query = "$querys $op and (datainicio >:datainicio AND datafim<:datafim)";
            $db = new ligacao();
            $conn = $db->open();
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':datainicio', $datainicio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':datafim', $datafim, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
            if ($key != "") {
            $query = "$querys  KEY=:KEY";
            $db = new ligacao();
            $conn = $db->open();
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':KEY', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $table = array();
        $rows = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        $table['data'] = $rows;
        $json = json_encode($table);
        echo ($json);

    }
}
```

> **Obs.:** Não se esqueça de tratar os dados vindos do POST antes de
>   chamá-los na sua classe, usando as funções [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: não conhecia esse tal filter_input

Comment: quero é ter varias funções no mesmo ficheiro php e chama-las por ajax enviando parameteros

Comment: @user2964140 é algo semelhante a isso que você quer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Comment: sim é isso https://gist.github.com/jonsuh/3739844#file-response-php-L12 encontrei este exemplo