# Recontar lentamente o numero de registros de uma tabela

Tags: php, css

Olá pessoal tenho um campo em meu site que exibe o número de registros de clientes cadastrados. Como recontar este registro de forma mais lenta para o usuário visualizar esta recontagem?

Exemplo: `Clientes cadastrados: <?php echo $admcadastros; ?>`

Aguardo ajuda!

Comment: Ou seja, você quer que o usuário do seu site veja o contador de clientes sendo incrementado: "Clientes cadastrados: 0", "Clientes cadastrados: 1", [...] "Clientes cadastrados: TOTAL" ? tipo, o contador vai incrementado em 1 a cada X segundos?

Comment: @tayllan isso mesmo! Correto

Comment: Talvez você queria dar uma olhada em `Easing Functions`, é o mesmo princípio das funções de Fade-In e Fade-Out o que você quer fazer, mas no caso, ao invés de afetar a opacidade de uma imagem, você quer que seja o Total de clientes multiplicado pelo valor da função. http://easings.net/pt

Comment: Tem uma demonstração funcional aqui mesmo no SOpt: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102170/como-usar-unidade-de-tempo-menor-que-milissegundos-em-um-setinterval-ou-settimeo/102175#102175

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) do JavaScript:

```js
var contador = document.getElementById('contador');
var TOTAL_CLIENTES = 10;

var intervalo = setInterval(function() {
  contador.innerHTML = parseInt(contador.innerHTML, 10) + 1;

  if (contador.innerHTML == TOTAL_CLIENTES) {
    clearInterval(intervalo);
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<p>Clientes cadastrados: <span id="contador">0</span></p>
```

O código acima vai incrementar o valor do `<span>` em 1 a cada 500 milisegundos. Você pode alterar o intervalo de incremento como quiser, deixar mais rápido ou mais lento.

`TOTAL_CLIENTES` é seu valor vindo do PHP:

```
var TOTAL_CLIENTES = <?php echo $admcadastros; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma meta tag pra atualizar sua página de tempos em tempos:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> // 5 segundos
```

Ou por AJAX, explicado seu funcionamento aqui:

[chamadas php por ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88443/chamadas-php-por-ajax)